# Memory management issues in iOS.Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.ios

While popping up the page which contains only button from page which contains back button with dispose method where i am releasing designer outlets its consuming memory.

```
partial class detailclass:UIViewController
{
public async override void ViewDidLoad()
{
base.ViewDidLoad();
back.TouchUpInside-=Back_TouchUpInside;
back.TouchUpInside+=Back_TouchUpInside;
}
public override void ViewWillDisappera(Boolean animated)
{
base.ViewWillDisappear(animated);
Dispose();
}
void Back_TouchUpInside(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
this.NavigationController.PopToRootViewController(true);
}
protected override void Dispose()
{
 this.ReleaseDesignerOutlets();
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: my ques is how to delete images that are getting stored in cache memory?